# MS Visual Studio C1083 for every project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I just encountered problem with Visual Studio 2013, when I get C1083 for every project/solution. Error I am getting looks like this one (path and name differ from project to project)

```
Error   1   error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'main.cpp': No such file or directory D:\what\c1xx    what
```

there is only one file, main.cpp containing just

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("hello world");
    while (1);
}
```

so nothing should be wrong there. Project folder contains

```
Debug
main.cpp
what.sdf
what.sln
what.vcxproj
what.vcxproj.filters
```

what I find strange, VisualStudio keeps claiming main.cpp does not exist even when I place absolute path to it in vcxproj instead of just filename.

I'd like to note that VisualStudio was working, stopped without me fiddling with anything and reinstalation nor repair did help.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any idea where it's getting 'No such file or directory D:\what\c1xx'?  Why is it referring to D:\what?

Comment: That is absolute path to the project, D:\what\main.cpp would be file with main. I tried looking for 'c1xx' in paths connected to C1083 but to no avail. Now I tried reseting all settings and no effect on the issue whatsoever.